# input[type=range] slow on Microsoft Edge / Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

Using a range input in MS Edge/IE browser appears to run slow when dragging the input thumb. All other browsers behave well.
Is it a common MS Edge/IE problem, or is something wrong with my HTML/CSS?

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            input[type=range] {
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <input id="slider1" type="range" min="0" max="5000" step="1" value="1"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you have any event listener attached to this slider?

Comment: Yes, but removing them doesn't make it faster. Even with this code above, the slider doesn't move as fast as my mouse drags it.

Comment: Are you running this in a VM? If so VM drag and drop performance is normally crappy.

Comment: No, I'm not running it on a VM.

Comment: can you please post any relevant scripts you are using?

Comment: It does not depend on any scripts. You can reproduce the effect using the code above only.

Comment: @epascarello Thank you!  I am indeed using a virtual machine and dragging the slider is very choppy.  Outside the VM I can point a browser at the web app and the slider is smooth as butter.  Thank you.